# ODE system solution with Mathematica or MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, mathematica

I need solution of this system with Mathematica or MATLAB:

$\frac{\partial f(i,j,t)}{\partial t}=\sum_{i_{0}<i}^{}\sum_{j_{0}}^{}a(i,j)b(i,j,i_{0},j_{0})f(i_{0},j_{0},t)-a(i,j)f(i,j,t)$

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more information on the problem you're having, what $a,b,f$ are, or is this just a general equation etc?

Comment: functions a and b are not important you can pick them arbitrary. i.e. a(i,j)=2i/j. i have problem when defining function f generally. and solving with ode45. yes this is general equation. each step for i and j i have a differential equation and for an upper limit (e.g. 5 or 50) i have 5 equations to solve simultaneously.. can you give me a pseudocode about it? @snulty